# jquery append elements until they will reach certain amount

Tags: jquery

I have an `<ul>` and I want to append `<li>` elements until they will reach the amount of `10`

How is the best practice to do this in jQuery?

It could be great also if the solution can consider that sometimes I can already have for example 5 `<li>`, so in this case I only want to append 5 more elements to reach the amount of 10...

Comment: You haven't posted what you've tried. Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `while` loop like

```
while(!$('li:gt(9)').length){
        $('ul').append('<li></li>');
    }
```

just use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to see if an eleventh element exists yet or not.

Comment: this is very close to what I hoped to find :) many thanks mate!

Comment: @neoDev, :gt() is zero-based index, so use 9 instead of 10

Answer (score 1):

Lets just assume that you have a variable that holds the number of li to be appended.
For loop is the best choice, you can control the number of iterations.

```
var counter = 10; // depends on desired count, 
for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    if ( !$( '#li_ID' ).length ) // check if li already exist
         $('ul').append('<li></li>')
}
```

Comment: this does not consider if I have already some existing elelemnts...

Comment: you didnt specify @.@

Comment: @maku - yes he did. Read the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @j08691 sorry my bad, updated my answer

Comment: now you updated it :) I didn't try yet but thanks for help guys!